# fatal error: 'unicode/usprep.h' file not found when installing php mongodb

Tags: macos, xampp, macports, icu

I'm trying to run

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/bin/pecl install mongodb
```

and i got

```
fatal error: 'unicode/usprep.h' file not found
```

I've found solutions using brew but on my mac I use mac ports, is there is a solution using `port`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finally did, I've manually installed the php extension following those steps:

1.I've downloaded mongodb php source from
https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb

2.Uncompress the tgz and go into the directory

3.`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/phpize`

4.`./configure --with-mongodb-sasl=no`

5.`make all`

6.`sudo make install`

7.add `extension=mongodb.so` at the end of php.ini

et voila